# Comparing between two user models

Tags: python, django

I have two models. UsersOne and UsersTwo. Both these databases looks like this:

```
class UsersOne(models.Model):
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    firstname    = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname     = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I am tyring to find every user with matching email in the UsersTwo model that. So if there are 10 users in UsersOne and 5 of them have matching email UsersTwo i want to write them out in a csv file.

So for example if user John, Doe, ***, jondoe@gmail.com also is a user in UserTwo model i want to make a query to get him.

So i have tried this.

```
import both models...

users_one = UsersOne.objects.all()

matching = []

for i in users_one:
     matching.append(UsersTwo.object.filter(email=users_one[i].email))
```

And i get this error:

```
QuerySet indices must be integers or slices, not User.`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems: `i` is not an index, but a `UserOne` object, and by `.append(…)` you are adding the duplicates as an element, not as elements of the list.

You can solve this with:

```
matching = []
for user in UsersOne.objects.all()
     matching += UsersTwo.object.filter(email=user.email)
```

But this is still inefficient: it will make a query for each item in `UsersOne`. You can boost efficiency with:

```
matching = UsersTwo.objects.filter(email__in=UserOne.objects.values('email'))
```

or for some databases, like [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), it is better to first materialize the list of `values`:

```
matching = UsersTwo.objects.filter(email__in=list(UserOne.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)))
```